# Pymongo : Insert data to a variable collection

Tags: python, mongodb, oop, pymongo, self

Imagine that this is my class, and I want to insert myObject to a collection. The name of the latter is variable and depends on a config object .

I tried this :

```
class MyClass(Object):

    def __init__(self, config):

        self.config = config
        self.db = config.db
        self.collection = config.db


    def on_data(self, myObject):
        self.db.self.collection.insert(myObject)
```

and this :

```
class MyClass(tObject):

    def __init__(self, config):

        self.config = config

        self.db = config.db       
        self.collection = config.db


    def on_data(self, myObject):
        self.db[self.collection].insert(myObject)
```

No one of those worked!

I tried also this :

```
class MyClass(tweepy.Object):

    def __init__(self, config):

        self.config = config
        self.connection = config.connection
        self.db = config.db
        self.collection = config.db


    def on_data(self, myObject):
        self.connection[self.db][self.collection].insert(myObject)
```

I had this error :

```
TypeError: name must be an instance of basestrin
```

Knowing that config is an instance of DBConfig :

```
class DBConfig():
    def __init__(self, db, collection):
        self.connection = Connection()
        self.db = self.connection[db]
        self.collection = self.db[collection]
```

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just looks like you have some typos in your sample classes.  Namely, you define `self.db` and `self.collection` to both `config.db`.

```
class MyClass(tweepy.Object):

    def __init__(self, config):
        self.config = config
        self.db = config.db
        # define `self.collection` appropriately
        self.collection = config.collection

    def on_data(self, tweet):
        # just use the collections insert method
        self.collection.insert(myObject)
```